# Spring: SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() returns Anonymousauthenticationtoken in iFrame

Tags: spring, spring-security

The page is running in iFrame (I was forced to by business partner).
If I run the page without iframe, this call

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

returns `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`

but if I run it in iframe, it returns:

`Anonymousauthenticationtoken`

How can I make it to return `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` in iframe?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your security configuration. Check for `X-Frame-Options` options.

Comment: For this page, I did not have `X-Frame-Options` enabled (no such header).  For other pages I have `X-Frame-Options` set to `sameorigin`.